# Session for window forms application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have written a windows form application in vb.net . Is there a way to sent variable value from login form to other form (from login to logout)? example when I login by admin account , I can access in to some form which normal account can't do this . I searched in the internet, a lot of people advice that build a instance class to save the variable  , but when I go to other form , the variable value = nothing .
how can I do that?
(sorry but my english is not well)
thankyou

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.  There a number of different strategies that can be employed.  Perhaps update your question with exactly where you at and we can take a look and advise

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. Your issue is basically that you just don't know how to pass data from one form to another, so that's what you actually need to research. What the data represents is actually irrelevant to your problem. You need to make more of an effort to identify the actual issue because this site is about specific issues. You should have taken the site tour when prompted.

Comment: @ jmcilhinney I tried in google and research a lot of issue in this site but they did not match my requirements and it is premission and not basically with me  sir.
thats why i'm asking in there . and if you feel that is wrong question, lets ignore that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easiest to use the Settings system for this. Go on Project menu, Properties, Settings tab on the left. Click to create a file if you need to. Create a user scoped boolean called IsAdmin

Upon login, set `Properties.Settings.Default.IsAdmin = <true or false depending on if the sper is an admin>`

Whenever you want to use `IsAdmin`, can do like:

```
configButton.Visible = Properties.Settings.Default.IsAdmin 'only show config button to admins etc
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, it was help me so much. I want to do this by code. Because my boss said that when when I login by admin account , for each go to another form the button user can click is different .then when go to another from , account will be check. it isn't permission by role .That why I want to save userID like session .

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying the solution works for you or not, but you can just put a string type setting instead of a boolean  and put user Id in it, then query it however you want